# For what values of $k$ is matrix invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, homework

I want to know what value $k$ can not be for the matrix

```
A = {{4, 0, 2}, {-1, 2, 0}, {3, 1 , k}}
```

to have an inverse (be invertible).

I now you use the `Inverse[A]` to find the inverse but that is not the assignment.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. This is for the Mathematica software package. You are looking for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: No i want to use mathematica to solve for it

Comment: OK, then start by showing us your matrix in MMA notation, i.e. as a list of lists, and anything else that you have tried. Also, think of the mathematical condition for a matrix to be invertible...

Comment: @MarcoB thank u I have updated

Comment: Thank you. So now, you probably know that a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is nonzero. So you could calculate the determinant symbolically (see [`Det`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det.html)), then use that expression to construct an equation to find the values for which the determinant is zero. You then solve the equation (e.g. using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)) to find `k`.

Comment: Thank u, I got it now @marcoB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having defined

```
A = {{4, 0, 2}, {-1, 2, 0}, {3, 1 , k}}
```

then

```
Solve[Det[A] == 0, k]
```

yields

```
 {{k -> 7/4}}
```

Comment: I get $7/4$ rather than your value. Are you using the matrix in the OP?

Comment: maybe i mistyped a number...